# Docusign - API connect JWT - consent_required

Tags: php, jwt, docusignapi

My goal: get a token to send a digital signature request (server to server)

Environnement : PHP, Symfony - Demo environment

Here is the error I am receiving when running the following code: **Error : "consent_required"**

My code :

```
class ServiceSignature
{   
    private $container;
    private $accessToken;
    private $accountId;
    private $signerName;
    private $signerEmail;
    private $fileNamePath;
    private $basePath;
    private $appPath;


    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container        = $container;
        $this->accountId        = "dc295354-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-f2e3a8813b1e";
        $this->basePath         = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi';
        $this->appPath          = $_ENV["FOLDER_UPDATE"];
        $this->accessToken      =  "";
        $this->private_key_path = "../docusign_private.pem";
        $this->private_key      = file_get_contents($this->private_key_path);
        $this->cle_integration  = "bdfeaf70-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-8a2ed57eb7ef";
        $this->audience         = "account-d.docusign.com";
        $this->permission_scopes= "signature impersonation";
        $this->token            = $this->getToken();
    }


    public function getToken()
    {
        $current_time = time ();
        $_token = [
            "iss" => $this->cle_integration,
            "sub" => $this->accountId,
            "aud" => $this->audience,
            "scope" => $this->permission_scopes,
            "nbf" => $current_time,
            "exp" => $current_time + 60*1000
        ];


        $jwt  = JWT::encode($_token, $this->private_key, 'RS256');
        $headers = ['Accept' => 'application/json'];
        $data = ['grant_type' => 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer', 'assertion' => $jwt];
        $body = Unirest\Request\Body::form($data);
        $response = Unirest\Request::post("https://{$this->audience}/oauth/token", $headers, $body);
        if (strpos($response->raw_body, '<html>') !== false) {
            throw new Exception("An error response was received!\n\n");
        }

        $json = $response->body;
        dump($json);
        die();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please remove references to your secret keys and IK. You don't want that floating around the web.

Comment: Answered below. If it helps you out, be sure to upvote and accept. Thanks! –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely that the User GUID that you've supplied has not yet granted consent.

Follow [this guide for obtaining consent](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/obtaining-consent) and you should be good to go.

An excerpt:

> When an application authenticates to perform actions on behalf of a
>   user, that user will be asked to grant consent for the set of scopes
>   (sets of permissions) that the application has requested unless they
>   have previously already granted that consent.
>
> To begin authentication and obtain consent, your application redirects
>   the user's browser to the DocuSign authorization URI. Note that this
>   is not a standard GET request and cannot be directly sent by the
>   application. Instead, the user's browser is redirected to an
>   authorization request URI and the request is sent from there to the
>   account server.